# 'Detached entity passed to persist' in OpenAPI UI, but not in Postman

Tags: java, database, jpa, openapi, quarkus

I am creating a quarkus application where a certain `PriceRequest` entity should be stored in the DB. This is a short version of the entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_price_request")
public class PriceRequest extends PanacheEntity {
  @Column
  public String buildingType;
  @Column
  public int squareMeters;
}
```

Now, I would like to test a post call which tries to save a PriceRequest into the DB. It calls the `addPriceRequest` function from the repository which you can find below.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class PriceRequestRepository implements PanacheRepository<PriceRequest> {
    @Transactional
    public void addPriceRequest(PriceRequest priceRequest) {
        priceRequest.setCreationDate(LocalDateTime.now());
        priceRequest.persistAndFlush();
    }

    @Transactional
    public PriceRequest findPriceRequestById(Long id) {
        return findById(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<PriceRequest> findAllPriceRequests() {
        return findAll().stream().toList();
    }
}
```

When testing this via a Postman call, everything works. When testing this with the OpenAPI UI, the following error pops up:

```
 HTTP Request to /price-request failed, error id: a5caae7f-5daa-49ef-8358-0e57b9895a1a-6: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: be.backeit.domain.PriceRequest
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.persist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:88)
```

Whats wrong in my code? Do I need to add some extra annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different approaches using of Panache within the Quarkus application:

1. using the active record pattern through PanacheEntity
2. using the repository pattern through PanacheRepository

If you use PanacheEntity you shouldn't use PanacheRepository. And vice versa don't extend PanacheEntity if you work with PanacheRepository

So I think the problem is you mixed both approaches in your addPriceRequest() method.

Comment: Using the active record pattern, it still does not work. However with the repository pattern it works. But now is my question: Why is this the case? And why am I not able to get it to work with the active record pattern?

Comment: No idea I cannot  see your current version of code, the result should be the same in both ways